# App need Google Games Play when installed app crashed

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client, leaderboard

Hello I have trying to use LeaderBoards in android app.

____________________________EDIT________________________________________________

Ok, now I tried follow this link [Guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin)

I create new project for test. I Have code like in Giude.

If want log-in was showed popup for Google Game download... OK, downloaded it.

BUT if I open app again app crashed. I don't know why. 
(I launch app in phone no, simulator)

Do you have some ideas? 
[I have new project with ONLY code from guide. + basegameUtils]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
    private boolean mAutoStartSignInflow = true;
    private boolean mSignInClicked = false;
    private boolean mAutoStartSignInFlow=false;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);


            // Create the Google Api Client with access to the Play Games services
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                    // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
                    .build();

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
      //  mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        if (!mInSignInFlow && !mExplicitSignOut) {
            // auto sign in
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // The player is signed in. Hide the sign-in button and allow the
        // player to proceed.

        // show sign-out button, hide the sign-in button
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // (your code here: update UI, enable functionality that depends on sign in, etc)

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
            // already resolving
            return;
        }

        // if the sign-in button was clicked or if auto sign-in is enabled,
        // launch the sign-in flow
        if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
            mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;

            // Attempt to resolve the connection failure using BaseGameUtils.
            // The R.string.signin_other_error value should reference a generic
            // error string in your strings.xml file, such as "There was
            // an issue with sign-in, please try again later."
            if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this,
                    mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                    RC_SIGN_IN, String.valueOf(R.string.signin_other_error))) {
                mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            }
        }

        // Put code here to display the sign-in button
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        // Attempt to reconnect
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            } else {
                // Bring up an error dialog to alert the user that sign-in
                // failed. The R.string.signin_failure should reference an error
                // string in your strings.xml file that tells the user they
                // could not be signed in, such as "Unable to sign in."
                BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,
                        requestCode, resultCode, R.string.signin_failure);
            }
        }
    }


    // Call when the sign-in button is clicked
    private void signInClicked() {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    // Call when the sign-out button is clicked
    private void signOutclicked() {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            // start the asynchronous sign in flow
            mSignInClicked = true;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
            // sign out.
            mSignInClicked = false;
            Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);

            // show sign-in button, hide the sign-out button
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
            // user explicitly signed out, so turn off auto sign in
            mExplicitSignOut = true;
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }


    boolean mExplicitSignOut = false;
    boolean mInSignInFlow = false; // set to true when you're in the middle of the
    // sign in flow, to know you should not attempt
    // to connect in onStart()
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;  // initialized in onCreate


}
```

Comment: Leaderboards don't need Google+ sign in. What gave you that idea? Google Play Games has its own sign in.

Comment: so now how implements leaderboard? I zhing so I need google+ and in leaderbard have google name and score.. Please give mi advice. or Example code.. Thanks. for leaderboards (whatever, without google+)

Comment: Did you try following the [Google Play Games Sign In guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin)?

Comment: no, when I follow instruction, leaderboard work good?

Comment: Yep, they wrote the guide for a reason :)

Comment: @ianhanniballake  I tried But I have a problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my mistake..

I was  haven't this

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@strings/app_id" />
```

in `<application></application>`

and it was a problem.